# Python - Parse a specific tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the word "helloworld" from the html tag below:

```
<td bgcolor="#000000" style="width:100px;">helloworld</td>
```

Here is my code so far:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
text = '<td bgcolor="#000000" style="width:100px;">helloworld</td>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
soup.findAll('td', style="width:100px")
print soup
```

But this just prints the tag again, how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `soup.find('td', style="width:100").get_text()`.

Comment: 2 things: 1.) you are printing `soup` which is your full variable so of course it is printing the whole tag. 2.) `soup.findAll` will return a list that you are currently not assigning to a variable and so the reference to that list is not being used. you need something like `for tag in soup.findAll(...): print tag.string`

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for your help Alecxe, unfortunately I get no results i.e. "None" message after running the script.